# How to display time from DateTime field in DateTimePicker in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, datetimepicker

Lots of troubles with DateTime fields today...

I have a DateTime field that I want to separate and display as a date in one DateTimePicker and a time in another DTP. This is what I tried:

```
dtp_date.Value = myRow.myDateTime.Date;
dtp_time.Value = myRow.myDateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

I'm getting an error that says it can't convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'System.DateTime'. I guess I just don't understand what I need to do differently. All it will do is display the time of day right now, not the one stored in my DateTime field.

Anyone know how to extract the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the DateTimePicker a valid date AND time.  Hide the date on display and only show the time using DateTimePickerFormat.Time

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime( DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 5, 30, 0 )
```

Pop in your time values from the myRow.myDateTime field

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `CustomFormat` property of your `DateTimePicker` control:

```
dtp_date.CustomFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
dtp_date.Value = myRow.myDateTime;
```

That should show the time portion of your date.

Comment: Interesting, but any way to do it without a custom format with them both included? I'm using separate DTPs so they can change just the date or the time as needed.

Comment: @ThatProgrammer I'm not sure how you could do that for just the time. You could try creating a new `DateTime` instance based on just the time portion of your `myRow.myDateTime`, but I assume that without a custom format it will show as `00/00/0001 <your time here>`.

Comment: Hmm. I tried the custom format, but I don't have 'CultureInfo' as an option. All I had was 'CultureInfoConverter'.

Comment: You should add `using System.Globalization;` to your class header.

Comment: I did that, but it's still just displaying the date.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a New DateTime object with the values you need: 
`dtp_time.Value = new DateTime(0,0,0,myRow.myDateTime.Hour,myRow.myDateTime.Minute, myRow.myDateTime.Second);`